# Build Boost.Python with specific conda environnment and MSVC on Windows

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, conda

I'm trying to install Python.Boost, however, after downloading it, I fail to build the package. I'm doing so through the following .bat script on Windows 7. (I also do not have admin right on my computer and have several version of MSVC installed) For building it, I followed the instructions from here :

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/hello.html
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/no_install_quickstart.html

As I couldn't find the user-config.jam file on my computer, I created one at the root of the boost folder.

```
CALL C:\Appl\Miniconda3_32bits\Scripts\activate py34
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86

cd /D C:\Appl\boost_1_67_0

(
echo using msvc : 10.0 : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" ;
echo using python
echo            : 3.4
echo            : "C:\Appl\Miniconda3_32bits\envs\py34\python.exe"
echo            : "C:\Appl\Miniconda3_32bits\envs\py34\include"
echo            : "C:\Appl\Miniconda3_32bits\envs\py34\libs"
echo            : ^<define^>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
echo           ;
) > user-config.jam

CALL bootstrap vc10

SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Appl\boost_1_67_0\;
cd C:\Appl\boost_1_67_0\libs\python\example\quickstart
echo %PATH%
PAUSE
CALL C:\Appl\boost_1_67_0\b2 toolset=msvc --verbose-test test
PAUSE
```

I get the following warning between the two PAUSE statements (the french statement is "Cannot open the include file"):

```
warning: no Python configured in user-config.jam
warning: will use default configuration
...found 34 targets...
...updating 10 targets...
compile-c-c++ extending.obj
extending.cpp
extending.cpp(5) : fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'boost/python/class.hpp' : No such file or directory

    call "..\bin\standalone\msvc\msvc-10.0\msvc-setup.bat" x86 >nul
 cl /Zm800 -nologo @"extending.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ extending.obj...
...skipped <p.>extending.pyd for lack of <p.>extending.obj...
...skipped <p.>test_ext for lack of <p.>extending.pyd...
compile-c-c++ embedding.obj
embedding.cpp
embedding.cpp(6) : fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'boost/python.hpp' : No such file or directory

    call "..\bin\standalone\msvc\msvc-10.0\msvc-setup.bat" x86 >nul
 cl /Zm800 -nologo @"embedding.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ embedding.obj...
...skipped <p.>test_embed.exe for lack of <p.>embedding.obj...
...skipped <p.>test_embed.run for lack of <p.>test_embed.exe...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 6 targets...
```

I have several Python installation on my computer (32 and 64bits), and I would like to use the 32 version, as the C++ I want to interface is using external DLL that were compiled in 32 bits. However, it seems that I cannot set a specific conda environement for Boost.

Also, the first statement in order to activate the environment seems to be override by the second one : I don't really understand what the second one is doing but it seemed to be necessary to compile basic hello World in C++ from command line.